# Projecting Screen Coordinates onto a World-Coordinate axis-ray

Tags: math, opengl

I am trying to make a world-axis-aligned translation gizmo to convert movement by the mouse into axis-constrained world-movement. My plan was to find the end-points of the axis-ray as bounded by the projection frustum and project those world coordinates into screen coordinates to get a line (a line projected into screen-coordinates). Then project the mouse delta values onto that line(find the intercept point of the axis-line and the perpendicular line which passes through the mouse-delta-point) to find a point which lays along the line to represent the final transformation point;

finally I wanted to unproject that new 2d screen-coordinate from the screen-projected-line back into world coordinates (such that it lies on the original axis-ray). I would then move the gizmo to that world-coordinate.

The problem is that I don't understand how to do the final projection from screen-coordinates back into world-coordinates such that the coordinate lies on the axis-ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unproject the position into world positions (one on the near plane and one on the far plane) and construct a ray from these points. Then the world point you are looking for is the intersection of the axis with this very ray. Since you know that there must be an intersection, it is sufficient to calculate the line parameters for a plane only.